# Actualizacion de aplicacion de escritorio en c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo una aplicacion de escritorio hecha en c# ya instalada en diferentes pcs y me gustaria hacerle unos cambios extra

> tengo la duda si hay una manera de actualizar mi app una vez que termine sin necesidad de desintalar la primera e instalar la nueva version

Comment: Puedes usar ClickOnce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utiliziar ClickOnce. Permite colocar la aplicación en un recurso compartido para que lo descarguen todos los clientes de la red.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2019